# Yii2: How to configure bootstrap modal to work with escape key and Select2?

Tags: php, yii2, bootstrap-modal

I have a Yii2 Modal widget and I need to close the modal when escape key is pressed.

```
<?= Modal::widget([
    'id' => 'modal_view',
    'options' => [
        'tabindex' => false, // important for Select2 to work properly
    ]
]) ?>
```

I found the [Bootstrap Modal Options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals-options) and the [clientOptions](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/806/render-form-in-popup-via-ajax-create-and-update-with-ajax-validation-also-load-any-page-via-ajax-yii-2-0-2-3) but it didn't work:
[image: Modal options from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals-options]

[image: Trying 'keyboard' => FALSE but it doesn't work]

```
<?= Modal::widget([
    'id' => 'modal_view',
    'size' => 'modal-lg',
    'options' => [
        'tabindex' => false, // important for Select2 to work properly
    ],
    'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => true]
]) ?>
```

Comment: updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

For the `ESC` key to work correctly you need to set the `tabindex="-1"` for the bootstrap modal.

Don't know if you are assigning it `false` for the select2 to work correctly is because of layout issues? because for me it works correctly with `-1`. See image
[image]

So change your code to

```
<?= Modal::widget([
    'id' => 'modal_view',
    'size' => 'modal-lg',
    'options' => [
        'tabindex' => "-1", 
    ],
    'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => true]
]) ?>
```

You can see this [discussion](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4663) for details.

### EDIT

The issue you were facing is related to the focus.Bootstrap registers a listener to the focusin event which checks whether the focused element is either the overlay itself or a descendent of it 
You can fix this by overwriting the `enforceFocus` function which registers the event on the modal.

Add the following line of javascript in your view

#### Bootstrap 3

```
$js=<<<JS
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
JS;
$this->registerJs($js, View::POS_READY);
```

#### Bootstrap 4

```
$js=<<<JS
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function() {};
JS;
$this->registerJs($js, View::POS_READY);
```

Comment: It works, but now i can't write in the select2 of my form. My select2 needs 'tabindex' => true.

Comment: @RobySottini i see what were you referring to.. see the update